# WELD-001210: Warning when validating beans.xml against xsd. schema_reference.4

Tags: weblogic12c

When I try to start the instance in weblogic 12, it receives the following warning and it does not start:

```
    <Warning> <org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap> <BEA-000000> <WELD-001210: Warning when validating file:/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/WS/tmp/_WL_user/ws-acces/u0zfqu/war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@8 against xsd.
schema_reference.4: Fallo al leer el documento de esquema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', porque 
    1) no se ha encontrado el documento; 
    2) no se ha podido leer el documento; 3) el elemento raíz del documento no es <xsd:schema>.>
```

The server does not have access to the internet, in the maven dependencies, the scheme is there, I have tried to put the version
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd, without version, also with clashpath:

Being deployed in weblogic 10, it works perfectly.

my beans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
```

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declares all resources in your XML to be local, and package them with the application.